# Linting errors for unused/undefined variables in React

Tags: reactjs, eslint, vite, lint

I'm writing some React code and noticed from my tutorial videos that their unused variables have the red squiggly lines under unused/undefined variables. For me the unused/undefined variables are greyed out, which is not helpful when there are more lines of code in a Component file.

[package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jscL.png)

[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmm3T.png)

I believe my React project is configured using Vite, and I've tried editing the "Lint" key in my package.json file, almost exhausted all VSCode/ESLint setting but still didn't get it to work. I even tried setting up external .eslintrc.json file but I don't think that's the solution either. Any idea of what I'm missing or doing it wrong?